# strtok_s behaviour with consecutive delimiters

Tags: c, strtok

I'm parsing 3 values in parallel which are separated with a specific separator.

```
token1 = strtok_s(str1, separator, &nextToken1);
token2 = strtok_s(str2, separator, &nextToken2);
token3 = strtok_s(str3, separator, &nextToken3);

while ((token1 != NULL) && (token2 != NULL) && (token3 != NULL))
{
    //...
    token1 = strtok_s(NULL, separator, &nextToken1);
    token2 = strtok_s(NULL, separator, &nextToken2);
    token3 = strtok_s(NULL, separator, &nextToken3);
}
```

Suppose '-' is my separator. The behaviour is that a string with no consecutive separators:

```
1-2-3-45
```

would effectively result in each of these parts:

```
1
2
3
45
```

However, a string with two consecutive separators:

```
1-2--3-45
```

will not yield a 0 length string, that one is skipped so that the result is:

```
1
2
3
45
```

and not

```
1
2

3
45
```

What workaround or strategy would be better suited to obtain all the actual parts, including the 0-length ones? I'd like to avoid re-implementing strtok_s, if possible.

Comment: strtok() is evil because it modifies the input string. Other than that, I'm curious about the answer to this.

Comment: In my case, strtok can modify the string all it wants, I'm keeping the original and working on a copy.

Comment: I got into Microsoft's strtok_s.inl and saw that indeed this is the expected behaviour because there is a skip of leading delimiters to the first "non-delimiter" character. Hmm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `strtok()` ignores empty tokens. Even though you said you wish to avoid doing that, there is no other way but to parse it yourself, using for example `strchr()` to find the next delimiter and then copying the token to a temporary variable for processing. This way you can handle empty tokens whichever way you please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the way this function works. It's more appropriate for tasks like parsing words where multiple whitespace characters should not be treated as empty words.

I've done a lot of parsing. I would simply write my own parser here, where the code examines one character at a time. It's not that difficult and you can make it behave exactly how you need. As an example, I've posted some C++ code to parse a CSV file in my article [Reading and Writing CSV Files in MFC](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-mfc)