# Split a single column of data with comma delimiters into multiple columns in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis, split

I have a table in SQL Server with 3 columns, one of which is a data column containing rows of concatenated columns delimited by commas. The first row is also the header row of the new table I want to create. so basically I want to turn this.

```
Data      | ID | Source 
====================
a,b,c,d,e | 1  | a.csv

f,g,h,i,j | 2  | b.csv
```

into

```
a | b | c | d | e
=================
f | g | h | i | j
```

Using SSIS, The only way i could think of doing it is using a dump into a text file of the data column and then re-read it as an flat file source, but I'd rather avoid creating extra unnecessary files

EDIT: Sorry Im using SSIS 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is to read the file as is. 
And Split those values in a script task.

So from source go to a script task.
Then in the script task as input column, select the column containing those values (InputColumn1). Then specify the output columns (If I am right I see you have 5, so specify 5 (OutputColumn1 - 5)).

After that is done, go to the script itself (C#).

Under:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
}
```

Put the following code in there:

```
var ColumnValue = Row.InputColumn1.Split(',');

Row.OutputColumn1 = ColumnValue[0];
Row.OutputColumn2 = ColumnValue[1];
Row.OutputColumn3 = ColumnValue[2];
Row.OutputColumn4 = ColumnValue[3];
Row.OutputColumn5 = ColumnValue[4];
```

After the script task all the columns from the Source as well as the OutputCoulmns1-5 will be available and you can do what you have to.

OUTPUT

```
 Data      | ID | Source |OutputColumn1 |OutputColumn2|  etc. 3-5
 ================================================================
 a,b,c,d,e | 1  | a.csv  |  a           |  b

 f,g,h,i,j | 2  | b.csv  |  f           |  g
```

Please ask if something is not clear.

Comment: I followed your instructions, but it seems to have brought the InputColumn1 as a Blob so doesn't allow the Split method. I tried using the ToString().Split(',') (get a Index was outside the bounds of the array error) but that didnt work either. i went into the BufferWrapper.cs file and saw that the InputColumn1 was of type Blob and was returning a BlobColumn, tried replacing the type with string but then get a Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn' to type 'System.String' error .Could it be to do with that?

Comment: To be honest, I have never worked with a Blob. Can you not change that in your source task? Change the type it is received as?

Comment: Don't edit BufferWrapper.cs, it's auto generated. You can only modify the datatypes for the inputs in the script component editor. What you actually need is a `data conversion` component to handle your blob. Place it before your script componenet and convert the column to string

Comment: Thanks, Changed the source from DT_TEXT to DT_STR and worked like a charm :)

Comment: Happy to hear that. Glad I could point in the right direction. Along with TsSkTo :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Token](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213216.aspx) expression to isolate strings delimited by well, delimiters.

Use a `derived column transformation` and something like this:

> TOKEN([Name_of_your_Column], "," , 1)

Should give you "a"

> TOKEN([Name_of_your_Column], "," , 2)

Should give you "b"

You can also set up a simple *transformation* `script component`. Use your "DATA" column as an input and add as many outputs as you need. Use the [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method and you're set.

> string[] myNewColumns = inputColumn.split(",");

Comment: I'm guessing this is an expression in 2012, I'm actually using 2008, sorry for the confusion

Comment: It wouldn't have mattered.. I had no clue SQL 2008 didn't have these expressions.

Comment: TOKEN is quite useful in SQL Server 2012. Note there is an interesting [problem with token counting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917758/why-does-ssis-token-function-fail-to-count-adjacent-column-delimiters) when your delimited string includes some empty fields.