# SSIS: Trim field for specific part of string

Tags: sql, string, sharepoint, ssis, expression

My Situation:

I have an Employee field which I am getting through a SharePoint list.
The current value I am getting is this:

`EmployeeID;Employee Firstname Employee Lastname`

Say for example:

`43;Stacky Stackerflow`

What I Need is either the ID alone without the `;` or the First and Lastname,
but I have no way of telling if the ID is gonna be 1, 2 or 3 Digits Long or in anyway tell how big the Names are gonna be.
Is there a way to cut these using any of the Tools in SSIS ? If so how ? And if not, is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Copy and paste from my answer here :[Split a single column of data with comma delimiters into multiple columns in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653995/split-a-single-column-of-data-with-comma-delimiters-into-multiple-columns-in-ssi/19654637#19654637)

You can use the [Token](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213216.aspx) expression to isolate strings delimited by well, delimiters.

> TOKEN(character_expression, delimiter_string, occurrence)

so

> TOKEN(EmployeeField, ";", 1)

will give you your ID

You can also set up a simple transformation script component. Use your "DATA" column as an input and add as many outputs as you need. Use the split method and you're set.

```
string[] myNewColumns = inputColumn.split(";");
```

Comment: Would you know how i could get the First and Lastname only,
that come after the ';' ?

Comment: Use a token expression with semiclolon AND a space for the delimiter string. Take a look at the msdn documentation. They show how to use multiple delimiters with token. Itsin that link in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Because this is tagged SQL, I'll answer using that syntax:

```
select left(Employee, charindex(';', Employee) - 1)
```

If you want this as an integer, then use:

```
select (case when isnumeric(left(Employee, charindex(';', Employee) - 1)) = 1
             then cast(left(Employee, charindex(';', Employee) - 1) as int)
        end) as EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- If all the values in the list are separated by ";" then you just need to import the file with a ";" separator, you won't need to specify any lengths.

2.- If only this field has a ";" then you can use a Derived Column on SSIS, with a SUBSTRING SQL function, similar to this:

```
    select SUBSTRING('first;second', 1, CHARINDEX(';', 'first;second') - 1) AS First,
    SUBSTRING('first;second', CHARINDEX(';', 'first;second') + 1, 8000) AS SecondV
```

Replace the string with in the above example "first;second" with your source column name.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer,
but CHARINDEX isn't available in SSIS