# Parse one field into several, based on delimiter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am trying to figure out a way to parse 1 field into 8 different fields using SSIS.  I'm open to a C# solution or a VB solution.  I came up with a way to do it in SQL Server, but because my team is doing a lot of things in SSIS now, I'd like to have a SSIS solution to keep things streamlined and efficient.  I looked online and found one option, in the link below.

[Split a single column of data with comma delimiters into multiple columns in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653995/split-a-single-column-of-data-with-comma-delimiters-into-multiple-columns-in-ssi)

I'm not really sure how that works, if it even works.  My sample data looks like this:

`Purchase | 345 | USD | GT | TF456577 | DG | 125 | KTMDC`

I can have 0 to 7 pipe characters, so I need to split one field into a max of eight fields.

[image]

### Update

Hadi, I am making a couple small edits.  Can you look at the screenshot and tell me what's wrong here?  Also, I never found the `DT-STR` option.  Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this using a script component**

*In this answer, I will assume that the data source is an SQL Server Table, with one column `Column0`*

In the Integration Service Package, follow these steps:

1. Add a `Data Flow Task`
2. Create an OLEDB Connection manager, and configure it
3. In the `Data Flow Task` add an `OLEDB Source` and choose the Table that contains the Column you need to split
4. Add a `Script Component` *(Set its type to Transformation)*
5. Connect the `OLEDB Source` to the script component
6. Change that Script Language to Visual Basic
7. In the `Script Component` Select `Column0` as Input
8. Go To the Inputs Outputs Tab
9. Add 8 Columns to `Output0` *(ex: `outColumn0, outColumn1 ... outColumn8`)* with `DT-STR` data type
10. In the Script window write the following script:

    ```
    Imports System.Linq

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        If Not Row.Column0_IsNull AndAlso
            Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Column0.Trim) Then

            Dim strColumn As String = Row.Column0
            Dim intVerticalBarCount As Integer

            intVerticalBarCount = strColumn.Count(Function(x) x = CChar("|"))

            If intVerticalBarCount <= 8 Then strColumn = strColumn & "".PadRight((8 - intVerticalBarCount), CChar("|"))

            Dim strOutputColumns As String() = strColumn.Split(CChar("|"))

            Row.outColumn0 = strOutputColumns(0)
            Row.outColumn1 = strOutputColumns(1)
            Row.outColumn2 = strOutputColumns(2)
            Row.outColumn3 = strOutputColumns(3)
            Row.outColumn4 = strOutputColumns(4)
            Row.outColumn5 = strOutputColumns(5)
            Row.outColumn6 = strOutputColumns(6)
            Row.outColumn7 = strOutputColumns(7)


        Else

            Row.outColumn0_IsNull = True
            Row.outColumn1_IsNull = True
            Row.outColumn2_IsNull = True
            Row.outColumn3_IsNull = True
            Row.outColumn4_IsNull = True
            Row.outColumn5_IsNull = True
            Row.outColumn6_IsNull = True
            Row.outColumn7_IsNull = True



        End If


    End Sub
    ```

In the code above, first we get the number of occurrence of vertical bars `|` in the column; if it is less than 8, we add the missing vertical bars, then we split the column and assign it to the output columns.

Comment: Thanks so much!!  This looks very promising!!  I will try it as soon as I get back to the office on Monday!!