# SQL Server using CTE for Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, common-table-expression

I have an asterisk delimited flat file, I import it into a single column in a table to check for errors. Once happy, I then want to split it up and insert it into a table with a 17 columns that correspond to each field in the delimited single column.

The column looks like this

```
5*0121**01300421142116*CW*WAREHOUSE AND PREMISES*8497395000*01-APR-2016****18017262000*25-APR-2016*096G*26621354212*25-APR-2016*17-MAY-2016*
```

I use this to split it and insert it:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        check_content,
        SUBSTRING(check_content, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('*', check_content), 0) - 1, LEN(check_content))) sString,
        NULLIF(CHARINDEX('*', check_content), 0) cIndex,
        1 Lvl
    FROM   
        delimiter_check_reval T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        check_content,
        SUBSTRING(check_content, cindex + 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('*', check_content, cindex + 1), 0) - 1 - cindex, LEN(check_content))),
        NULLIF(CHARINDEX('*', check_content, cindex + 1), 0),
        lvl + 1
    FROM   
        cte
    WHERE  
        cindex IS NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO raw_epoch_historic
            (revaluation_id,
             billing_authority_code,
             ndr_community_code,
             ba_reference_number,
             primary_and_secondary_description_code,
             primary_description_text,
             unique_address_reference_number,
             effective_date,
             composite_indicator,
             rateable_value,
             appeal_settlement_code,
             assessment_reference,
             list_alteration_date,
             scat_code_and_suffix,
             case_number,
             historic_from_date,
             historic_to_date)
SELECT Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 1 THEN sstring
           END) val1,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 2 THEN sstring
           END) val2,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 3 THEN sstring
           END) val3,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 4 THEN sstring
           END) val4,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 5 THEN sstring
           END) val5,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 6 THEN sstring
           END) val6,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 7 THEN sstring
           END) val7,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 8 THEN sstring
           END) val8,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 9 THEN sstring
           END) val9,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 10 THEN sstring
           END) val10,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 11 THEN sstring
           END) val11,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 12 THEN sstring
           END) val12,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 13 THEN sstring
           END) val13,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 14 THEN sstring
           END) val14,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 15 THEN sstring
           END) val15,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 16 THEN sstring
           END) val16,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN lvl = 17 THEN sstring
           END) va1l7
--, datastring OriginalDataString
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY check_content; `
```

it works perfectly on a reasonable number of rows but the whole file is 2.5m rows and i then get this error:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.WORKFILE GROUP large record overflow storage:  140739078979584' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

And it fails to insert.

We got no inserted rows.

Comment: Are you on sql server 2022, then you can use string_split with positional argument which should simplify your code. Otherwise, i'd probably convert to json and use OPENJSON, since your CTE keeps passing the original long argument string, there will be way too much data in memory after a couple of iterations

Comment: As above, a recursive CTE is a poor way to split strings, there are much better ways in all versions of SQL Server. I personally would not be tackling this in SQL Server though, why not split the fields during your import? SSIS is built for exactly this kind of processing. If you want to import first, do some checks, then copy, you can still use a dataflow along with a script component to extract from your imported data, [split the column on the delimeter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19658817/1048425), and import to another table

Comment: As siggemannen says, string_split is great and should use that.  If you are on an older version, you can build a string_split function (searchable online) for an older version that can help you parse it.  string_split exists in 2016 and older.  If you're on a younger version, google search "string_split 2014" and you'll find a stackoverflow link to a function coded for you already.  Good Luck!

Comment: the reason im doing it this way is because the data flow in ssis often misses a record if it has an error in this format, im also combining some data to get this in a raw state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on *tokenization*.

It has no limitation on numbers of rows to process.

You would need to complete the `SELECT` clause, and include the rest of the columns with the appropriate data types.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GdK_dcnX)

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, check_content VARCHAR(2048));
INSERT @tbl (check_content) VALUES
('5*0121**01300421142116*CW*WAREHOUSE AND PREMISES*8497395000*01-APR-2016****18017262000*25-APR-2016*096G*26621354212*25-APR-2016*17-MAY-2016*');

-- INSERT INTO raw_epoch_historic ...
SELECT t.ID
  , c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'INT') as revaluation_id
  , c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') as billing_authority_code
--  continue here up to 17th column, via r[1 to 17]
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(check_content, '*', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

Comment: Thanks very much this works as expected. The issue is its too slow, 2.5m records on a serious server was 2 hours and counting when i stopped it. it might be easier for me to export it and reimport it as a flat file. Many thanks anyway.