# strtok behavior

Tags: c, strtok

```
 int main ()
 {

    char str[] ="kk,12,,23,4,,,3434,3,33,,,";
    char * valarr;
    int count=0;
    valarr = strtok(str,","); 
    while(valarr != '\0')
    {
               valarr = strtok(NULL,","); 
    count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
   return 0;
  }
```

In above program the output is 7.

It seems that the strtok is tokenizing consecutive commas at once.

Instead of consecutive commas I can introduce a blank in between but
Is there a way to overcome this so that I have empty space also in the count ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977836/strtok-s-behaviour-with-consecutive-delimiters - although the answers here are better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct. [The documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) states this pretty clearly:

> A sequence of two or more contiguous delimiter characters in the parsed string is considered to be a single delimiter.

That's just how `strtok()` is supposed to work. You might be better of rolling your own, which will also free you from `strtok()`'s nastiness.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: NO
At least using strtok, [check this](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/) to learn what's better for your application.